# PHPExcel Issue in server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

In controller i used.

```
$this->load->library("PHPExcel");
```

Its working on local machine but in main server have error...

```
Error : NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found in Autoloader.php on line 36
```

What will be the issue?

Thank You in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

check the permission of the PHPExcel.php file in library. this file have permission to access or not. because this file not have access permission then the occur this type of error.

Comment: which file to be comment?

Comment: check the permission of the PHPExcel.php file in library. this file have permission to access or not. because this file not have access permission then the occur this type of error.

Comment: Gave full permission. But still error continues. But in local it works perfect.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found in Autoloader.php on line 36

Answer (score 0):

you have PHP module xmlwriter enabled on server to run PHPExcel,,, check the requirements for PHPExcel.

Comment: check your .htaccess also. commonly  Error: 500 raised due to .htaccess configuration

Comment: in .htaccess what will be the issue? i couldn't get any.

Comment: some times routing in .htaccess may cause Error: 500.,, so i said that,

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_String' not found in Autoloader.php on line 36